# Unable to get data from 2 CSF file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am not getting data from CSV files. I create 2 different HTTP requests and made 2 different CSV files and now from 1 CSV I want to get data for 1 HTTP request and from 2 CSV file I want to get data for 2 HTTP request but currently from 1 CSV file both HTTP requests get data.
Can any one help me how to post data from both CSV files?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you two CSV Data Set Config elements configured to read data from CSV files?

Comment: Also can you share the schema view of the test plan (JMX). You can generate the schema view from menu in JMeter GUI  Tools --> Generate Schema View

Answer (score 0):

Just use different names for variables coming from CSV file 1 used for HTTP Request 1 vs ones coming from CSV file 2 for the 2 other HTTP
requests.

First CSV Data Set:

[image: CSV 1]

Second CSV Data Set:

[image: CSV 2]

Except for that, there is nothing special and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your feedback but I want to know that, In both csv files I have different parameter, I have 2 different users to log in Like one user parameters are for Passenger and other user parameters are for Driver. Now when I run my script that time, passenger script run successfully and get data from passenger CSV file but second driver http request is run successfully but all parameters are getting from passenger script instead of driver CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If your 2 CSV files are independent just use different variable names for 2 requests and that should be it.

If your 2 CSV files depend on each other, i.e. you want to extract specific value from CSV file 2 based on the value from CSV fiel 1 - you won't be able to use CSV Data Set Config, you will need to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), see  [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) for more details

Comment: Thank you for sharing your feedback but I want to know that, In both csv files I have different parameter, I have 2 different users to log in Like one user parameters are for Passenger and other user parameters are for Driver.

Comment: Now when I run my script that time, passenger script run successfully and get data from passenger CSV file but second driver http request is run successfully but all parameters are getting from passenger script instead of driver CSV file.